# Is TeXample site still alive?

Tags: discussion, code-example

I hope this is the right place to ask this.

Does anyone know what happened to [TeXample](http://www.texample.net/)?

I submitted a TikZ example one year ago, and it still hasn't appeared. The last examples were added in November 2012 [**Edit**: *this is wrong, many examples have been added since then*].

I sent an email to Stefan Kottwitz, who is supposed to be webmaster, but never got any answer.

Or is it so that TeXample is now superseded by tex.SE? In that case, there should be an anouncement on the TeXample landing page...

Comment: Latest addition for me is http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/doa-diagram/: very recent!

Comment: I would be very surprised if it wasn't alive any more. Usually Stefan is very responsive. Maybe you have the wrong email address?

Comment: I notice that this question isn't really on-topic: not about TeX-Sx (so not meta).

Comment: @JosephWright I agree with you. And, since the question was based on a wrong assumption on my part, I suggest to close it.

Comment: @JosephWright voted

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[TeXample](http://texample.net) is alive. I added 6 examples just in the last few days. In 2013 I added 15 examples, which isn't so much, I agree ([chronological list](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/all/date/)). I slowed down since I've got my second child, still I wanted to add all submissions and still plan to add some of the great examples from TeX.SE.

I'm very sorry that I missed to add your example. I scanned through my older emails and found it again, the link to github with your code. I also found my reply I sent the same day, and your following update notice from April 1. Just to clarify (it's still my fault to not follow up your code), perhaps you would like to remove just the parts with November 2012 and never got an answer, in the question above, if you like.

Back to the point, TeXample is alive and will be further updated and maintained. I would be glad to receive further contributions to add to the gallery, so please don't hesitate to send me, if you like. In case it might take time, just send me a friendly reminder email so nothing should get lost.

Btw. the comment feature was just disabled a short time ago, because the spam rate was too high (more than 3000 each months) and some came through the filter, causing too much moderation work. It will be enabled again, once I implemented a better spam filter.

What I usually do, when adding a submission:

- I read the code and try to understand
- I might break long lines and improve indentation for readability
- Sometimes I try to explain the science or tech topic (if I just got the code)
- I might change to a standard document class such as article - I often get `standalone` (still a bit new, not every user may have installed it), and the `minimal` class
- I usually insert preview package and settings, it's in the download code but not in the way in the visible code on the web page
- Find good topic tags, but also tags for used features which I see in the code
- Compiling and inserting, compiling and producing image and thumbnails is quick thanks to Kjell's great scripts
- Editing database info (author, date, tags)

Thank you, Olivier, your example is now online: [Shake and Rattle on a planar pendulum example](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/shake-rattle-pendulum/)

Put it to the test, challenge me, and submit examples.

**Update:** waving the TeX.SE flag, added this evening TeX.SE answer code by Paul Gaborit, Gonzalo Medina, and JLDiaz (backlinks there):

[image: Fitting text to a shape][image: Table in the shape of an arrow][image: Snowflakes with TikZ]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great answer, Stefan. And huge thanks for maintaining TeXample! Sorry that about the misunderstanding about my example not being published. I'm not implying that you were adding to few example, I just thought that you had stopped adding any, which was wrong on my part. Keep up the good work! Cheers